# Infinitely scrollable <tbody> element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a React component that renders a table containing a bunch of (tabular) data.  It has a fixed header, and a scrollbar on the `<tbody>`.

As the amount of data has increased, I am looking at solutions for infinite scrolling, particularly [react-infinite](https://github.com/seatgeek/react-infinite).

This tool works *nearly* perfectly, rendering a pair of `<div>`s along with some padding etc, and adding/removing content as the user scrolls.  It's nice and snappy.

However, my console is riddled with complaints:

```
Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <div> cannot appear as a child of <tbody>.
Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <tr> cannot appear as a child of <div>.
```

which is completely understandable, however the page itself behaves exactly how I want want.

```
class Table extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    columns: PT.array,
    data: PT.array
  }

  render () {
    const {
      columns,
      data
    } = this.props;

    const header = this.renderHeaderRow(columns);
    const body = this.renderDataRows(data, columns); // [<tr>]
    const footer = this.renderFooterRow(columns);

    return (
      <table className={this.props.className}>
        <thead>
          {header}
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {
            /* This injects 2 nested <div>s, which aren't allowed
               as children of <tbody>, nor parent of <tr> :(
            */
          }
          <Infinite elementHeight={50}
                    containerHeight={750}
                    infiniteLoadBeginEdgeOffset={0}
                    timeScrollStateLastsForAfterUserScrolls={0}>
            {body}
          </Infinite>
        </tbody>

        <tfoot>
          {footer}
        </tfoot>
      </table>
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried

```
<Infinite>
  <table> ... </table>
<Infinite>
```

But this (of course) results in the entire table existing inside a scrollable box.  I need just the `<tbody>` to be scrollable.

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <Infinite>
          ...
        </Infinite>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
<table>
```

but even after tweaking CSS everywhere to try and make it work, this also breaks everything and feels like an ugly hack.

Is there a solution for an infinitely-scrolling `<tbody>` element that does not "break the rules" of HTML?

Comment: have you tried putting it in a <td>

Comment: Yes, sorry I missed that in my example

Comment: What do you mean " this also breaks everything"?

Comment: @Alohci I mean it "breaks everything" (tm).  I can't really elaborate without basically dumping my source code here, which I'm not allowed to do.  This is a complex react app, the table itself is a multitude of components.  #itsnotthatsimple.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is 'no'... in the traditional sense. Assuming you want a scrolling table, and `react-infinite` is limited to creating [**`<div>`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table) elements, then you cannot have valid markup. This is due to `<div>` being invalid anywhere inside of a **[`<table>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table)**, aside from the table cell (**[`<td>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td)**) elements themselves.

Having said that, do you really need a *table*? One possible solution would be to create flow content that *behaves* like a table, by making use of the various tabular **[`display` properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)**:

```css
.table {
  display: table;
}

.table-row {
  display: table-row;
}

.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <!--
  React Infinite
  <div>
  -->
    <div class="table-row">
      <div class="table-cell">
        Content
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        Content
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-row">
      <div class="table-cell">
        Content
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        Content
      </div>
    </div>
  <!--
  React Infinite
  </div>
  -->
</div>
```

This way, you can still have the exact same layout, with the **[W3C Validator](https://validator.w3.org)** considering your markup to be valid as well.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Unfortunately this table's style is a product of many (historical) hours work, and is all designed with flexbox.. I can't really get out of using the `<table>` :(